# Predicting memory usage of a process

Tags: windows, memory, windows-7, parallel-processing

I work on an application that uses parallel computing. To know how many tasks I can run in parallel, I need to be able to predict the amount of memory each task will occupy.

I know (approximately) how much data of each type each task will use.

How do I go about predicting memory usage? Perform operations research using process metrics? Sum up many sizeof()s?

I work on Windows 7, x64 edition. Each task runs in a separate process.

Answer (score 1):

So what you are actually trying to do is to find the maximal amount of memory each task will take, approximately.

There is a .net function that does exactly that. It's called [`Process::PeakWorkingSet64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.peakworkingset64.aspx):

```
Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
int maxSizeInKb = (int) p.PeakWorkingSet64() / (float) 1024;
Console.WriteLine(maxSizeInKb + "KB");
```

Add this code before your process exits and will will get the info you want, in Kbytes.

Answer (score 0):

At its peak running time, call [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for one of the task and get the memory usage of particular task(process). You may also want to get a sampling of this data by calling this function on different tasks at different times to get more precise average.